# Get the one year before date for a given date in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having a variable which would be containing a date...

```
end_date = '3/15/2019'
```

I want the output as:

```
start_date = '3/15/2018'
```

Can anyone help me how to write the code for this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a date strictly 365 days before a given date:

```
import datetime
(datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, '%m/%d/%Y') - datetime.timedelta(days=365)).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

'03/15/2018'
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's always a string you can slice and subtract 1 (after casting to int):

```
end_date = '3/15/2019'

start_date = end_date[:-4] + str(int(end_date[-4:])-1)

print(start_date)

>>> 3/15/2018
```

Comment: Don't forget about February 29!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the library, arrow, which supports you to shift the time by unit (from  seconds to years). Moreover, it can deal with leap year!

```
import arrow


date_format = 'M/D/YYYY'
end_date = '2/29/2016'

# shift by years:
start_date = arrow.get(end_date, date_format).shift(years=-1)
start_date = start_date.format(date_format)
print(start_date)

>>> '2/28/2015'

# shift by 365 days:
start_date = arrow.get(end_date, date_format).shift(days=-365)
start_date = start_date.format(date_format)
print(start_date)

>>> '3/1/2015'
```

document: https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/